# How do you remove KVO from a weak property?

Tags: objective-c, ios, macos, automatic-ref-counting

I have a view (we'll call this view A) that has a `weak` property to its superview (view B). View A KVO's its superview, view B. Since view A's reference to view B is a weak property (to prevent a retain cycle), how can I remove the observer (A observing B)? View A's reference to view B gets nil'd out before I have a chance to remove it.

A outlives B since the view controller has a strong reference to A. Here's the leaking log message:

```
An instance 0x9ac5200 of class UITableView was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it. Observation info was leaked, and may even become mistakenly attached to some other object. Set a breakpoint on NSKVODeallocateBreak to stop here in the debugger. Here's the current observation info:
<NSKeyValueObservationInfo 0x8660360> (
<NSKeyValueObservance 0x8660320: Observer: 0x8660020, Key path: contentOffset, Options: <New: YES, Old: NO, Prior: NO> Context: 0x8660020, Property: 0x864ac80>
)
```

B is a UITableView. Setting a breakpoint at `NSKVODeallocateBreak` yields useless results.

In A's `removeFromSuperview`, I try to remove the observer but A's reference to B is already `nil`.

Switching to `unsafe_unretained` and do things more manually or calling `[A removeFromSuperview]` in the view controller's `dealloc` solves the problem. I'd like to know how to solve this using a `weak` property though.

Here's the relevant code: https://gist.github.com/2822776

Answer (score 2):

I find any kind of code required specially for this case really unnecessary as removal can be automated.

With the introduction of ARC, Apple should have provide automatic removal of observers that would fix cases like this, but unfortunately they didn't. But I've made my own category that adds this lacking feature: https://github.com/krzysztofzablocki/SFObservers
I've explained how I did manage that on my blog: http://www.merowing.info/2012/03/automatic-removal-of-nsnotificationcenter-or-kvo-observers/

If you look at my solution you will notice, that it makes sure that original code is called, even if one of the methods call other ones, so that even if apple changes its internal behavior the category will still work fine :)

Comment: Your SFOvservers looks cool. I was hoping to use a less clever solution. Swizzling stuff on NSObject is a bit scary. Who knows what they'll change in iOS 6.

Comment: That's why my solution doesn't assume any order of original methods and instead calls the original code :-) So that is future proof if they change anything.

Answer (score 1):

You could define an explicit weak property referencing the superview and then observe `self` with a key path like `@"propertyReferringSuperview.propertyOfSuperview"`? When you get a KVO notification, you check if `self.propertyReferringSuperview == nil` and stop observing `@"propertyReferringSuperview.propertyOfSuperview"`.

Comment: I've tried this approach. When the weak reference to the superview gets niled out, KVO doesn't fire.

Comment: What a shame… Maybe try to insert cleanup into the custom setter `setPropertyReferringSuperview:`? I hope it gets called when the weak reference becomes `nil`. Actually, you can start and stop observing right in this setter.

Comment: This is a great answer. You don't need to remove yourself as an observer when the superview gets niled out. You can remain an observer until you are dealloced. So, just register to listen in init (even if your property is nil this is fine), then unregister in dealloc (or deinit).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding a weak property, you could just use the `superview` property and implement `willMoveToSuperview:` to add/remove the KVO observation.

```
- (void)willMoveToSuperview:(UIView *)newSuperview {
    [self.superview removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"contentOffset" context:context];
    [newSuperview addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"contentOffset" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:context];
    [super willMoveToSuperview:newSuperview]; // optional as default implementation does nothing
}
```

Comment: When `willMoveToSuperview:` is called, the weak property referencing view B (or `scrollView` in the Gist) is already `nil`.

Comment: Yes but you told that view B is A's superview. So you have no need for the `scrollView` property. Just use `superview`.